# How to CData property?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

How can I serialize a property with CData? I have tried a few different methods including making the original property XmlIgnore and introducing a property which returns XmlCDataSection. None have worked so far.

I have the following runnable console test which shows the error. How can I modify this to allow the Regex data to serialize and deserialize.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    [Serializable]
    public class MyRegex
    {
        public string Regex { get; set; }
    }
    public static class SerializerHelper<T>
    {
        public static string Serialize(T myobject)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, myobject);
            string xml = stringWriter.ToString();

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            xmlDoc.WriteTo(xw);

            return sw.ToString();
        }
        public static T DeSerialize(string xml)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyRegex original = new MyRegex { Regex = "\b[1-3]{1}\b#Must be a value of 1 to 3" };
            string xml = SerializerHelper<MyRegex>.Serialize(original);
            Console.WriteLine("--- SERIALIZE ---");
            Console.WriteLine(xml);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();


            Console.WriteLine("--- DESERIALIZE ---");
            MyRegex deSerial = SerializerHelper<MyRegex>.DeSerialize(xml);
            Console.WriteLine("Equals? " + (deSerial.Regex.Equals(original.Regex)));

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Console.ReadKey();");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional: Attempted replace method - not working**

```
    private string _regex;
    public string Regex
    {
        get { return _regex.Replace(@"\\", @"\").Replace("&amp;", "&").Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&quot;", "\"").Replace("&apos;", "'"); }
        set { _regex = value.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("\"", "&quot;").Replace("'", "&apos;"); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use CData here - the problem is that your Regex does not have the string "\b", it does have the \u0008 (BS) character - which is not what you need in the regular expression. If you escape the '\' in the MyRegex initialization, it should work:

```
MyRegex original = new MyRegex { Regex = "\\b[1-3]{1}\\b#Must be a value of 1 to 3" };
```

This console app is ready to run, and it serializes the data fine (using \b):

```
public class StackOverflow_6755014
{
    public class MyRegex
    {
        public string Regex { get; set; }
    }
    public static class SerializerHelper<T>
    {
        public static string Serialize(T myobject)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, myobject);
            string xml = stringWriter.ToString();

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            xmlDoc.WriteTo(xw);

            return sw.ToString();
        }
        public static T DeSerialize(string xml)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        MyRegex original = new MyRegex { Regex = "\\b[1-3]{1}\\b#Must be a value of 1 to 3" };
        string xml = SerializerHelper<MyRegex>.Serialize(original);
        Console.WriteLine("--- SERIALIZE ---");
        Console.WriteLine(xml);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();


        Console.WriteLine("--- DESERIALIZE ---");
        MyRegex deSerial = SerializerHelper<MyRegex>.DeSerialize(xml);
        Console.WriteLine("Equals? " + (deSerial.Regex.Equals(original.Regex)));

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Console.ReadKey();");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when serializing, regardless, \b or \\b will try to serialize as &#x8; which is invalid for XML. So I need to CDATA it. Regex - `<RegexString>&#x8;[1-3]{1}&#x8;#Must be a value of 1 to 3</RegexString>` RegexEscaped `<RegexString>&#x8;\\[1-3]\\{1}&#x8;\\#Must\\ be\\ a\\ value\\ of\\ 1\\ to\\ 3</RegexString>`

Comment: Well, when i use the following lines of hack under string xml in the serialize function. It works!     `xml = xml.Replace("<RegexString>", "<RegexString><![CDATA[");`
and `xml = xml.Replace("</RegexString>", "]]></RegexString>");` So how can i do this generically?

Comment: The console app above is ready to run. Please try it for yourselves.

Comment: \\b will serialize as "\b", which is what should be the regex pattern: `<MyRegex ...><Regex>\b[1-3]{1}\b#Must be a value of 1 to 3</Regex></MyRegex>`

Comment: How is the user passing the data? Is it from the command line or from some UI text? If so, you'll get the correct Regex string (try printing it out) - it's the const string you have in your program in the question which has the invalid (BS) character.

Comment: sorry i deleted my comment as i was researching replace methods. The data is being entered via a web textbox. I have edited my post showing my current replace attempt which is not working.

Comment: Yes, you are right about not needing \b. The textbox on the web app strips it for some reason. But our unit tests were testing it which is where the character got through. Unless an escape methods comes up.... we may be able to proceed with this irregularity.